# Why does setting creation date via setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error: on Mac fail on network drives

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

I am setting creation date of a file using the NSFileManager method
 setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error: and the NSFileCreationDate attribute. This normally works fine. However, when I do this on a Synology network share, it fails (returns FALSE and the file creation timestamp is not changed).

When copying a file to the same share using Finder, the creation date is retained, so it must be technically possible. All this was tried on Mojave. Does anyone know what's going on and what else I could try?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Problem resolved. We were writing other attributes in the same call, which made the call fail. Correcting that to just the file creation date fixed the problem.